# Function doesnt run in my class for my tkinter registration program

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

My main problem right now is that the methods/functions written below dont run. ive tried to see if the structure is the problem, like using master/parent but there is no fix. i've also tried deleting the 'def' line so no function is run and does display however the functions wouldn't work therefore the registration wouldn't work.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Register():
    def __init__(self, master, uName =None, pWord = None, UserEntry = None, passEntry = None): #constructor method, i wont be instantiating anything so thats why i passed in none for each variable
        self.uName = uName
        self.pWord = pWord
        self.UserEntry = UserEntry
        self.passEntry = passEntry
        
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("1920x1080")

#Here is a method used to store the username and passwords to the entry.
    def register_user(self, master): 
        self.usernameInfo = self.uName.get()
        self.passwordInfo = self.pWord.get()

        file = open(self.usernameInfo+".txt","w")
        file.write(self.usernameInfo)
        file.write(self.passwordInfo)
        file.close()

        self.UserEntry.delete(0,END)
        self.UserEntry.delete(0,END)

#a message will also pop up when the register button is clicked and the registration is successful. this register button is called from a command down on the below function

        self.regMessage = Label(master, text = "Registration Success", fg = "green", font=("Comic Sans MS", 11)).pack()
        
    def register(self, master): #here is the layout
 
        self.uName = StringVar()
        self.pWord = StringVar()

        self.reg = Label(master, bg='#00A2E8')
        self.reg.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.45, relheight=0.3 , relwidth=0.25, anchor="e")

        self.reg1 = Label(self.reg, bg='white')
        self.reg1.place(relx=0.005, rely=0.005, relheight=0.99 , relwidth=0.99)

        self.reg2 = Label(self.reg, bg = '#3F48CC', text ="REGISTER", fg="white", font=("Comic Sans MS", 56))
        self.reg2.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight= 0.23)
 
        self.RButton = Button(self.reg, text ="REGISTER",fg='white', bg="#3F48CC", font=("Comic Sans MS", 26), command = register_user)
        self.RButton.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.82, relwidth = 0.45, relheight= 0.15)

        self.userLabel =Label(self.reg, bg="white", text="Username", width=10,font=("Comic Sans MS",25))
        self.userLabel.place(x=1,y=87)

        self.UserEntry=Entry(self.reg, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), textvariable = uName)
        self.UserEntry.place(x= 200,y=100, width = 260, height = 40)
    
        self.passLabel = Label(self.reg, bg="white", text="Password", width=10,font=("Comic Sans MS",25))
        self.passLabel.place(x=0.5,y=180)
    
        self.passEntry = Entry(self.reg, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), textvariable = pWord)
        self.passEntry.place( x= 200, y = 190, width = 260, height = 40)
          
        

RWindow = Tk()
my_GUI = Register(RWindow)
RWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why would you expect anything to run when you're not referencing or calling your `Register.register()` method anywhere? Is your `Register()` class maybe supposed to inherit from some TKinter class?

Comment: You don't call any of those functions. When do you *expect* them to get called?

Comment: You presumably intended to call `self.register(master)` during your `__init__` function.  When you do that, you'll get a "name not found" error, because you have `command=regisger_user` where you meant to say `command=self.register_user`.

Comment: no but i want the method to run somehow., i'm not sure i would call in the method either

Answer (score 0):

first you never call the method `Register.register`.

you should replace :

`def register_user(self, master):` -> `def register_user(self):`

`def register(self, master):` -> `def register(self):`

and use `self.master` when needed.

you also need to use `self.` every time you use a variable (field) or a method of `Register`

Comment: So i replaced everything you said. instead of **master** i used **self.RWindow**. However I'm yet to see anything display. I'm sorry I'm a bit of a noob. I'm curious if you could help at all

Comment: do you get an empty window? did you call the Register.register? take a look at this [code](https://textbin.net/3lj4kxv0bq) and learn from the differences what went wrong.